Why YOLOv8 detects bunch of random objects
I'm using the YOLOv8 command-line interface (CLI) to run object detection on an image, but I'm getting unexpected results. The model seems to be detecting a bunch of random objects that aren't present in the image.
Here’s the command I'm using:
yolo predict model=yolov8n.pt source='https://ultralytics.com/images/bus.jpg'
When I run this, it produces a result similar to the one shown in the image below:


I have the same problem with video stream input, and setting confidence to >= 0.95 does not help either, output is still garbage (a bunch of objects not in the image).

The same problem and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78820748/alot-of-incorrect-detection-using-yolov8/78821012#78821012

Thank you so much, indeed that's the right answer.

I managed to resolve this by using torch, torchvision GPU version instead.
pip uninstall torch torchvision
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu124

Also check your CUDA version to match with the wheel version, mine is 12.4
