Bounding boxes/image detection are inaccurate when using Ultralytics YOLOv8
When using yolov8x-obb the bounding boxes and image detection are inaccurate. How do I fix this issue?
This is my code
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('yolov8x-obb')

results = model("boat.jpg", save=True, show=True)

This is my result: boat picture

one other person has asked this within the last few days... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78860154/why-yolov8-detects-bunch-of-random-objects and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78820748/alot-of-incorrect-detection-using-yolov8/78821012#78821012

@ChristophRackwitz thanks, closed this as duplicate and voted to close the other one as well
