Problem about Real Time Object Detection Web App with YOLO
When I use YOLO models on the camera, such as YOLOv7 and YOLOv10, they work efficiently. However, when I use YOLOv8, the bounding box only locates at the top-left corner of the camera, the labels change very quickly, and the accuracy is always over thousands. Can anyone explain that? I found a comment in the code: 'The output tensor of yolov7-tiny is [det_num, 7] while yolov10n is [1, all_boxes, 6]'. So what is it for YOLOv8n?
I try to fix the post-processing about YOLOv8 but nothing results.

There may be an issue with one of the previous Ultralytics versions, please look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78820748/a-lot-of-incorrect-detection-using-yolov8. Changing the version (upgrade to the latest) can help.

yolov8n detection output that has been trained on coco with 80 classes is [1,84,8400]
1 is batch_size.
84 is x+y+width+height+conf_each_class = 4 + 80
8400 is number of detected boxes.

Can you give me information about yolov3 4 5 6 ? Thank you!

i have not worked with yolov3 4 6. but yolov5 output is similar to yolov8. its outputs shape is [1, 8400, 84] instead of yolov8 output which is [1, 84, 8400]
